# Google Visualization Dashboard with filter and DataView

Tags: javascript, charts, google-visualization, dashboard

I have a DataTable that looks something like this:

```
+-------+---------+--------+
| month |  name   | income |
+-------+---------+--------+
| Jan   | Alice   | $5,000 |
| Feb   | Alice   | $3,000 |
| Mar   | Alice   | $4,500 |
| Jan   | Bob     | $2,750 |
| Feb   | Bob     | $8,000 |
| Mar   | Bob     | $1,000 |
| Jan   | Charlie | $3,500 |
| Feb   | Charlie | $4,100 |
| Mar   | Charlie | $3,900 |
  ...       ...       ...
```

I wish to display a Google Visualization with one ChartWrapper and one ControlWrapper.

The ChartWrapper will display a Table, but I only want this Table to show **the most recent month**. To do this I'm using `.setView()` on the ChartWrapper.

The ControlWrapper will wrap a CategoryFilter on the name column.

The issue I'm running into is that when I try to select a name, it throws an error: `Invalid row index ... Should be in range [0-...]`

I believe I'm getting this issue because `setView` accepts a static array of rows to display, but if the table is filtered then the rows to display will be different. I'm calling `setView` like so:

```
var recentRows = dataTable.getFilteredRows([
    {
        "column": 2,
        "minValue": dataTable.getColumnRange(2).max
    }
]);
chartWrapper.setView({
    "rows": recentRows
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

when using the `Dashboard` control,
the `ChartWrapper` and `ControlWrapper` need to be in sync and use the same data set

as you've found, setting the `view` property only on the chart throws this off

to correct, use a `DataView` to draw the dashboard,
as seen in the following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['controls']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['month', 'name', 'income'],
    [0, 'Alice', 5000],
    [1, 'Alice', 3000],
    [2, 'Alice', 4500],
    [0, 'Bob', 2750],
    [1, 'Bob', 8000],
    [2, 'Bob', 1000],
    [0, 'Charlie', 3500],
    [1, 'Charlie', 4100],
    [2, 'Charlie', 3900]
  ]);

  var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'control',
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'name',
      ui: {
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: true
      }
    }
  });

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'chart'
  });

  var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
  view.setRows(data.getFilteredRows([{
    column: 0,
    minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max
  }]));

  var dashboard = new google.visualization.Dashboard(
    document.getElementById('dashboard')
  );
  dashboard.bind(control, chart);
  dashboard.draw(view);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="control"></div>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

---

another option would be *not* to use a dashboard
draw each wrapper independently,
then listen for the `statechange` event on the control,
and draw the table accordingly

see following working snippet...

```js
google.charts.load('current', {
  callback: drawChart,
  packages: ['controls']
});

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['month', 'name', 'income'],
    [0, 'Alice', 5000],
    [1, 'Alice', 3000],
    [2, 'Alice', 4500],
    [0, 'Bob', 2750],
    [1, 'Bob', 8000],
    [2, 'Bob', 1000],
    [0, 'Charlie', 3500],
    [1, 'Charlie', 4100],
    [2, 'Charlie', 3900]
  ]);

  var control = new google.visualization.ControlWrapper({
    controlType: 'CategoryFilter',
    containerId: 'control',
    dataTable: data,
    options: {
      filterColumnLabel: 'name',
      ui: {
        allowTyping: false,
        allowMultiple: true
      }
    }
  });
  control.draw();

  var chart = new google.visualization.ChartWrapper({
    chartType: 'Table',
    containerId: 'chart',
    dataTable: data
  });

  google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'ready', drawTable);
  google.visualization.events.addListener(control, 'statechange', drawTable);
  drawTable();

  function drawTable() {
    var filters = [{
      column: 0,
      minValue: data.getColumnRange(0).max
    }];

    var selectedNames = control.getState().selectedValues;
    if (selectedNames.length > 0) {
      filters.push({
        column: 1,
        test: function (value, row, column, table) {
          return (selectedNames.indexOf(table.getValue(row, column)) > -1);
        }
      });
    }

    chart.setView({
      rows: data.getFilteredRows(filters)
    });
    chart.draw();
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="control"></div>
<div id="chart"></div>
```

Comment: Unfortunately this solves one problem but creates another, but I guess I'll find a new solution to the other problem :) The reason I have the other months in the first place is because elsewhere on the dashboard I show a line graph of the historic values. Upon filtering for a given name (which only shows a single row in the table for the "current" income) I want the line graph to **also** be filtered to show the historic values for that name. So effectively the table needs to show a subview of the view created by the filter.

Comment: use a dashboard for everything but the table, then use second option above to draw table...